# In a USB-OTG-enabled device, is OTG_ID an input?

Tags: usb

I want to make sure I understand this correctly, because there is a disagreement in my company and I don't want to argue before I'm 100% sure I know what I'm talking about.

In my understanding, in a USB-OTG enabled embedded Linux board, OTG_ID would be an *input* pin, which would would get pulled to ground when a device-mode receptacle is plugged in. The board would read the low state of this input pin and know that firmware needs to make it behave like a device.

This is as opposed to OTG_ID being the embedded Linux board's output *indicating* what mode it is operating it's USB port in.

Comment: A quick web search would have confirmed that you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the ID pin is an input on a connector.

It can be used to read what kind of USB adapter or cable is plugged into the OTG connector.

Basically the plugged in connector or cable tells the OTG device whether it should be in the host mode or in the device mode.

Answer (score 1):

Usb ID is an input to tell the otg usb controller if it should be in device or host mode. The ID pin is only in the otg usb ab mini/micro connector, and not on a usb A female or male, so the slave device has no way of telling if the otg device is in host mode aside from the normal usb dp/dn interaction.

A usb otg controller may have additional outputs that control power or other circuits by pulling it up or down to indicate host mode, but that's separate from the usb ID pin function.